# OAuth Connector Facebook - how to get email, address, and other user details for registration?

Tags: social-network, authentication-authorization

I'm using OAuth Connector on my Drupal Commerce websites to register users using their Facebook accounts.
I found out how to set user name for the registration field, but I can't do the same with email.
How to get Facebook email for the user registration form on my websites?